# Fuelphp remove public from base_url

Tags: fuelphp

I ran in to a problem what icant really solve with fuel php.

I added the htaccess to te root, now i can acces my site like this www.mysite.com/wlecome, se the public is removed, but i cant find a way to remove the public when i use the `Config::get('base_url');` and the `Response::redirect();`

The base_url in the config.php is set to null, if i pass the site url to it, that way the assets are not rendering correctly.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hint how to remove the public from these.

Thank you.

Comment: the lates, version 1.2.1

Comment: `base_url` set to null will detect the location of the files and build the path based upon that. It doesn't take into account `.htaccess`. You'll therefore need to set the `base_url` manually in config.php

Comment: if i set it manual it wont pull the css in

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like you've installed the complete FuelPHP installation INSIDE the docroot, instead of outside, and making the public folder your docroot, which is the recommended way of installation.

If this is the case, move everything in the public directory one folder up, so it's in the docroot again, and remove the public folder, which is no longer needed.

Note that a setup like this leaves your code accessible via the browser, so you might want to add some htaccess to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

I know its not the prettiest but i usually do this way.

I open up Config.php

and pass under base url

```
'site_url' => 'your site url here',
```

and you cann call it this way `Config::get('site_url');`

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a .htaccess you can set a VirtualHost to go from http://project.dev/ to /var/www/project/public